# Database design for Workflow based system

Tags: database, postgresql, database-design, relational-database

I am designing a database for a sales company having a complex workflow. The flow starts at Sales Officer, then go to Team Lead and finally Manager. Before approving a proposal, manager will send it to the Division Business Analyst. After getting remarks from dba, he may send the proposal back to sales officer for modification in the proposal. The manager may also reject the proposal. If satisfied, manager will forward it to Director, Sales. The tables designed so far as follows:-

```
Table: ProposalBasicData 

Id, Title, ProposalDate, Scope, Objective

Table: ProposalState

Id, Name
(Values - Forwarded , Approved ,  Returned  ,  Rejected)

Table: UserType

Id, Name
(Values - SalesOfficer, TeamLead,  Manager ,  DBA, DirectorSales)

Table: WorkFlow

Id, StartUserType, NextUserType, StateId, IsActive

Table: RequestAction 

Id, ProposalId, WorkFlowId, UserId, ActionDate
```

Please suggest regarding the design.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are many questions raised by such problems.  Ex:

- in your tables, Workflow defines transitions from state to state as changing the assignment from one user to the next.
- this can be an issue.  Lets say the user is sick, leaving, on vacation, ...  Then your flow is blocked.
- It does not allow for the group concept either.
- others (like I) would define a transitions table.  StartState, NextState.
- The workflow would be a list of transitions.
- Each transition requires the user to be of a certain type.  Or from a user management point of view, have a certain role, or be member of a group.

If your workflow is fixed and is not subject to change, your method could be ok.  But if the workflow is flexible or might be changed / adapted, you should go with something more flexible.

The type of setup you are talking about make me think of the Jira software (form Atlassian), where you define tickets, with status, workflows and users.  Is it possible for you to use (i.e purchasse or OpenSource) a workflow management tool?  It might be cheaper in the long run than building one.

Your model will potentially be expanded to include:

- clients.  Which client is the proposal for?
- who is the sales representative or account manager who is responsible for auditing the workflow and moving it forward?
- link to other systems: how does it link to purchasing, accounts receivable, ...

All this to day, this requires an in-depth analysis which is hard to do on a medium such as this (SO).

---

**EDIT: 20181004**

I added the following model following your comment.  I decided to put the workflow(s) in the database:

[image]

Notes (tables in alphabetical order):

- Employee

  - Each employee can be linked to n number of EmployeeRole via the Employee_has_EmployeeRole table.
- Proposal

  - An Employee is linked as the Sales Officer, since he initiates a proposal.
  - A workflow is linked since many workflows could exist for different proposals.
- Transition

  - Linked to State twice.  The start state and the end state.
  - An EmployeeRole is linked, to identify which role an employee must have to perform this transition.
  - Enforcing that will be done by the application.
- Workrlow_has_Transition

  - Links Transitions to Workflows.
  - The Employee who completed the transition is recorded here.
  - The date it was done is also kept here.
  - The OrderInWorkflow is just a number that allows you to order Workflow_has_Transition entries.
  - The application will have to make sure a Transition is not done before the others of lower order are done (i.e. DoneDate is null).
  - It will also validate that the Employee trying to complete it has the proper EmployeeRole.

Now, the employee group concept.  You can say that a group are employees with the same EmployeeRole.  Therefore, when a notification needs to be sent by your application, send it to all users with the required role for the Transition.  This avoids you having to create an EmployeeGroup table, which links employees together.

Application scenarios:

```
- Start a Proposal
    - Verify that the user trying to start a new one has the role "Sales Officer"
    - Collect basic information.
    - Link the Sales Officer to it (current user).
    - Link a Workflow to it.  Only propose the workflows which have at least 1 Workflow_has_Transition.
    - Send a notification to the Employee(s) which have the EmployeeRole for the first Workflow_has_Transition for this new Workflow.
    - These employees receive a notification.
- Progressing through the workflow
    - An employee receives a notification about a Proposal and it's "todo" Transition.
    - Employee views Proposal and Workflow (use the OrderInWorkflow to ORDER BY Transitions).
    - Employee approves if he has the proper EmployeeRole, fill DoneBy_idEmployee and DoneDate.
```

While going through your application scenarios, you will find gaps or missing items.

Ex.1 do you want to record the rejection of a Transition?  How would that be handled then?  You send a notification to the employees with the role for that Transition to review it?

Ex.2 do you want to keep the complete history of the proposal?  Ex. it Transition X is rejected twice, but approved the third time around.

There are many scenarios like this which will show the weaknesses of your model, which you fix as you complete this analysis.  Now it is not perfect, I did not put a lot of time on it.  But it is a starting point and illustrates my idea.

Comment: Thanks for replying. In my workflow, transition happens from usertype to usertype.  So if a user is sick, another user will be assigned that type. If in future, team lead needs to return proposal to sales representative, then that transition will be added to workflow table. Please let know your views.

Comment: The choice is to include the workflow in the database or not.  If not, the code needs to be changed to implement a new transition.  If it is, it makes the code more generic, but you have to manage the combination of transitions to produce the workflow.

Comment: Thanks again. If transition table has to have  startstate, nextstate columns, can you please show me how to link it with user and user group?

Comment: Thank you. For my example, I will use States as SentBySalesOfficer, ApprovedByTL, SentToDba etc. If in future, Team Lead itself can reject a proposal, then just need to add a state in State table and add relevant transition in Transition table. Please comment.

Comment: Makes sense.  The best thing to do to test a design is to build scenarios and see if the structure can provide the result, without being overly complicated.

Comment: Regarding Ex 2, keeping history of the proposal - may I keep a version table against a requestid ? But problem is to know which fields of a proposal is modified each time. Otherwise, entire modified request has to be entered in a new row.

Comment: I see 2 possibilities.  If it is just for audit purpose, a simple text log (one per proposal) with actions taken is enough.  Or this log can be stored in another table, if database size is not an issue.  Then if you need to rollback to previous versions, you are right you have to keep everything.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you structure some where along this

```
ProposalBasicData {PBID,Title, ProposalDate,Scope,Objective} 
ProposalState {PSID,Name}
UserType {UTID,Name}
User {UID,Name,UTID(Usertype UTID FK) }
Request{ RID, StartUID, StartDate ,PSID, IsActive } 
RequestAction {AID,RID, RequesterUID, ReceiverUID, Date, Comments, IsCompleted }
```

as I think there could be multiple users of the same type, more over you would want to have comments on why it a RequestAction was rejected, A requester would make a requestAction to a receiver and if its completed it would show in the system make life easier when handling multiple requestActions of the same Request.

Hope this helps but i suggest you make a flow chart and look at what are all the possible use cases.